# What was it that "powered" Auto-Man and Cursor to allow them to exist in the real world?

Tags: tv, soft-sci-fi, hard-sci-fi, artificial-intelligence, hologram

In the early 80s sci-fi show  **Auto-Man** , the titular hero is essentially a humanoid form program made by a police-computer genius, and given physical shape in our reality. It was described as thus:

> Desi Arnaz Jr. played Walter Nebicher, a police scientist/Hollywood Nerd who's stuck in the computer room when he'd rather be out on the street. In response, he creates Automan (short for "Automatic Man", played by Chuck Wagner), an artificially intelligent holographic partner. Automan had the ability to do any action he’s seen on video, and interface with any computer system. He was also aided by Cursor, a blinking ball of light who could become virtually any object Automan needed, such as various vehicles or civilian clothing.

Now, Nebicher being a "scientific genius" was fine... but it still gave **no concrete explanation as to HOW Automan just "manifested" in his lab from computer code to physical form out of nothing!** The simple explanation is that Auto was artificially intelligent, so he could *think* for himself, and that all of his creations were basically "hard light holograms"... but again, with *no* kind of projector, or special high tech computer, or power surge from lightning or *anything* to further empower his form, the explanation is empty!

The closest the show ever got to "explaining" was Auto saying this a in voice-over:

> "Given enough power, a hologram can sound real, look real...and even *feel* real!"

Again, which is fine, as a means of explaining the holograms themselves. But a normal, everyday 1980s office computer [which ITSELF *shouldn't* have the sheer *processing power* to allow for *that kind* of A.I. to function!] wouldn't be **capable** of "projecting" such a hologram without any help!

So, again... how *exactly* did Automan and Cursor just "pop" into existence?????

Comment: The novelisation isn't much help. He just comes "from the computer's chipboards"; http://www.editing.org.uk/aesoprods/automan.htm#details

Comment: @Valorumwait...there was a **novelization????**

Comment: There was indeed. And you can pick it up for the princely sum of £2; https://www.amazon.co.uk/Automan-Target-book-Martin-Noble/dp/0426199758/ref=sr_1_2?keywords=automan&qid=1568146002&s=books&sr=1-2

Comment: @Valorum niiiiice! Actually, the novel itself seems to be selling for 0.02 pounds sterling. So the SHIPPING would cost more than the BOOK!

Comment: Yes. They'll send it 2nd Class (for 60p) and pocket the difference.